# How to trigger the manual deployment in Azure DevOps release pipeline from API

Tags: azure, rest, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-devops-rest-api

I'm able to queue a new release in Azure DevOps release pipeline with the next codes:

```
public async Task QueueRelease(string releaseDefinitionName)
{
    string teamProjectName = GetTeamProjectName();

    using (var connection = Authenticate())
    using (var releaseClient = connection.GetClient<ReleaseHttpClient2>())
    using (var buildClient = connection.GetClient<BuildHttpClient>())
    {
        var releaseDefinition = (await releaseClient.GetReleaseDefinitionsAsync2(teamProjectName, releaseDefinitionName, ReleaseDefinitionExpands.Artifacts)).SingleOrDefault();
        var primaryArtifact = releaseDefinition.Artifacts.Where(a => a.IsPrimary).SingleOrDefault();
        var projectName = primaryArtifact.DefinitionReference["project"].Id;
        var buildDefinitionId = Convert.ToInt32(primaryArtifact.DefinitionReference["definition"].Id);

        // Get the latest successful build from the project and build definition id
        var lastBuild = buildClient.GetBuildsAsync(projectName, new[] { buildDefinitionId }, statusFilter: BuildStatus.Completed).Result
                                    .OrderByDescending(b => b.Id)
                                    .FirstOrDefault();

        // Create the draft release, and associate it to the latest corresponding build
        var metadata = new ReleaseStartMetadata
        {
            DefinitionId = releaseDefinition.Id,
            IsDraft = true,
            Description = "Draft",
            Artifacts = new[]
            {
                new ArtifactMetadata
                {
                    Alias = primaryArtifact.Alias,
                    InstanceReference = new BuildVersion
                    {
                        Id = lastBuild.Id.ToString(),
                        Name = lastBuild.BuildNumber
                    }
                }
            }
        };
        var release = await releaseClient.CreateReleaseAsync(metadata, teamProjectName);

        // Activate the release
        var updateMetadata = new ReleaseUpdateMetadata { Status = ReleaseStatus.Active, Comment = "Test release" };
        release = await releaseClient.UpdateReleaseResourceAsync(updateMetadata, teamProjectName, release.Id);

        release.Environments[0].Status = EnvironmentStatus.InProgress;
        release = await releaseClient.UpdateReleaseAsync(release, teamProjectName, release.Id);
    }
}
```

However the release definition that I want to use, has the trigger setting "Manual only". And I don't want to change the release definition.

[image: Release definition]

After the release has been added to the queue, I still need to go to Azure DevOps portal and click on "Deploy" to start the release process per environment.

[image: Manual trigger]

Is there a way to start the "manual trigger" via API?

Answer (score 0):

you can try the following:

```
// Activate the release
var updateMetadata = new ReleaseUpdateMetadata { Status = ReleaseStatus.Active, Comment = "Activate Release" };
release = await releaseHttpClient.UpdateReleaseResourceAsync(updateMetadata, teamProjectName, release.Id).ConfigureAwait(false);

// Trigger the deployment on a specific environment
release.Environments[0].Status = EnvironmentStatus.InProgress;
release = await releaseHttpClient.UpdateReleaseAsync(release, teamProjectName, release.Id).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**